# Changing Dashboard Settings From Configuration File: PG Admin4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am trying to find a way to easily deploy a change to everybody in my large group using PG Admin 4.

Our goal is to reduce performance issues that can be caused by a few of the dashboard settings.

I need to find the necessary file to change the value of: show activity, show graph data points, show graphs and show mouse hover tooltip, to false.

I have already looked through the documentation and cannot seem to find how to do this clearly stated anywhere.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Changing the values in *initpy*

The changed values are not reflected in the web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for the dashboard module are per user basis, you can use preference dialog to change the values.

Refer the docs: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/preferences.html#the-dashboards-node

Goto `Dashboard -> Display` to turn on/off show activity, show graph data points, show graphs and show mouse hover tooltip etc

If you have many deployments then what you can do is change the settings for one instance and save the preference then copy the `pgadmin4.db` file from that instance and paste it on every other deployments where you want to disable the Dashboard.

**Note:** Make sure you don't have any saved password in pgAdmin4 for any database servers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am having trouble locating pgadmin4.db. I forgot to mention that all of our deployments are on windows 7. All materials I have found referencing the file online, is referring to linux deployments.

Comment: You can find it on `C:\Users\{Your_User}\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin`

Comment: You sir, have been a great help!